# Multiplying A Coefficient by an Indexed Multiplier using Generating Functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, derivatives, generating-functions

If I have a particular exponential generating function,

$$G(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

then what would be the generating function for

$$H(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)a_n\frac{x^n}{n!}$$ in terms of $G(x)$?  I know that I can change it to

$$H(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty na_n\frac{x^n}{n!}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\frac{x^n}{n!}=J(x)+G(x)$$

Now I know that 
$$G'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty na_n\frac{x^{n-1}}{n!}$$ and so

$$H(x)=xG'(x)+G(x)$$

Is there a way to write $H$ without the derivative of $G$?

I would like $H$ as a function in terms of strictly $G$, and without a $G'$ term.

Comment: why is it so problematic to have $H$ expressed through $G'$?

Comment: Wouldn't achieving this basically give a differential equation that $G$ has to satisfy, and therefore more or less characterize $G$ (or, equivalently, the sequence $(a_n)_n$; while you seek an expression applicable to any $G$, i.e. to any sequence $(a_n)_n$)?

Comment: No, because the solution would depend upon the choice of $(a_n)$ since this determines what $G'(x)$ is -- take for example $G_1(x)=e^x$ and $G_2(x)=\sin x$.

Comment: @William I don't quite get what you say. If I have both $H(x) = \Phi(x,G(x))$ and $H(x) = xG'(x) + G(x)$ for all $x$, then I get $\Phi(x, G(x)) = xG'(x) + G(x)$ for all $x$, i.e. a differential equation of the form $$G^\prime(x) = \Psi(x,G(x)).$$ Along with $G(0)$ and $G^\prime(0)$ (i.e., only $a_0$ and $a_1$), this differential equation characterizes $G$ -- doesn't it? (If not, where did I go haywire?)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, so we might already be in agreement. My point is that $\Psi$ depends specifically on the choice of $(a_n)_n$ so that the equation does not admit of any specific solution until we have a choice of $(a_n)_n$, and since multiple choices of $(a_n)_n$ are possible, there are multiple $G$'s which can satisfy the equation.

Comment: For instance, if $G(x)=e^x$ then $\Psi(u,v)=v$, whereas this is not true for all such $G(x)$.

Comment: Oh, that's the misunderstanding. The way I understand the question, the OP wants a relation ("a function $\Phi$") that is **independent** of the $a_n$'s, the same way that the expression $H(x) = xG^\prime(x)+G(x)$ is the same for every sequence $(a_n)_n$. But that is not possible, since it it were then this (along with the current expression $H(x) = xG^\prime(x)+G(x)$ )  would actually completely characterize $(a_n)_n$ (up to the choice of $a_0$ and $a_1$)

Comment: To answer @gt6989b, it is not problematic. I just tried for a while to see if it were possible.  I have a particular recurrence relation i am trying to find a EGF for and i solved recurrence for a particular $a_n$ but it was $(n+1)a_n$, and this is what drove the question.  I might post a new question to help with the EGF problem, but was interested in the possibility of solving in terms of $G(x)$ and not $G'(x)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will not be possible in general. Indeed, if you have both $H(x) = \Phi(x,G(x))$ and $H(x) = xG'(x) + G(x)$ for all $x$ (where $\Phi$ is a nice, regular  function), then you can derive an expression of the form $\Phi(x, G(x)) = xG'(x) + G(x)$ for all $x$, i.e. a differential equation of the form $$G^\prime(x) = \Psi(x,G(x)).$$
(where $\Psi$ is regular/"smooth enough"). Along with $G(0)$ and $G^\prime(0)$ (i.e., only $a_0$ and $a_1$), this differential equation will then entirely characterize $G$ -- while you are hoping to get a general formula that works for any $G$ defined by its generating sequence $(a_n)_n$.

Answer (score 4):

It shouldn't be possible to give a more simplified expression which is valid in general, since both $G(x)$ and $G'(x)$ depend on the choice of coefficients $(a_n)_n$ (albeit in a different manner).

For example, let $G_1(x)=e^x$ and $G_2(x)=\sin x$. Then:

$$H_1(x)=(x+1)G_1(x)$$

$$H_2(x)=xG_2(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)+G_2(x)$$

Thus while knowledge of $(a_n)_n$ should allow you in many cases to write $H(x)$ solely in terms of $G(x)$, how this will be accomplished will depend specifically on the choice of $(a_n)_n$, and as the example above shows, the results from different choices will not necessarily be reconcilable with each other, i.e. since the above two formulas (I believe) cannot be writted as special cases of a formula involving only $G(x)$ and not $G'(x)$.